# Cannot decide Model Associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and having a hard time figuring out what is the best association I can create for my models. The models I have are:

- User
- Article
- List
- ArticleLink
- ArticleMeta
- etc..

Here, User can create many `Articles` and `Lists`, an `Article` and `List` can belong to multiple `Lists`, an `Article` can have multiple `ArticleLinks` and `ArticleMeta`. I also want to delete all the references of a model wrt `User` when it is deleted. For example when an `User` deletes a `List`, all the reference of the `List` should be deleted from join tables.

Also please let me know what would be the most efficient way to insert records in each model and retrive records as well

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at the Active Record Associations docs, it's really good to learn the basics about Model Associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I went through the doc and I could only come up with association has_and_belong_to_many for User,Article and List. And has_many for Article and ArticleLinks,..etc. is this the right association?
 However, I am having hard time trying to insert records and in particular how to fetch records. For example, I would like to fetch all the articles for a user that don't belong to any list.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all your answers over this link
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

As example

```
rails generate scaffold Articles name:string category:string lists:references
```

or

```
rails generate scaffold ArticleLinks name:string Article:references
```

Comment: This does not answer my question.